# Get attribute using XPath with TinyXPath & TinyXML

Tags: c++, xml, xpath

I'm trying to write a function that will get me the attribute of a set of XML nodes in a document using XPath with the TinyXPath library, but I cannot seem to figure it out.  I find the documentation on TinyXPath is not very enlightening either.  Can someone assist me?

```
std::string XMLDocument::GetXPathAttribute(const std::string& attribute)
{
    TiXmlElement* Root = document.RootElement();
    std::string attributevalue;
    if (Root)
    {
        int pos = attribute.find('@');  //make sure the xpath string is for an attribute search
        if (pos != 0xffffffff)
        {
            TinyXPath::xpath_processor proc(Root,attribute.c_str()); 
            TinyXPath::expression_result xresult = proc.er_compute_xpath();

            TinyXPath::node_set* ns = xresult.nsp_get_node_set(); // Get node set from XPath expression, however, I think it might only get me the attribute??

            _ASSERTE(ns != NULL);
            TiXmlAttribute* attrib = (TiXmlAttribute*)ns->XAp_get_attribute_in_set(0);  // This always fails because my node set never contains anything...
            return attributevalue;  // need my attribute value to be in string format

        }

    }
}
```

usage:

```
XMLDocument doc;
std::string attrib;
attrib = doc.GetXPathAttribute("@Myattribute");
```

sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Test />
<Element>Tony</Element>
<Element2 Myattribute="12">Tb</Element2>
```

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose without seeing sample XML. Are you sure that the specified element exists on the document element?

Comment: Where is the XPath expression?

Comment: That's not well-formed XML. Might be part of your issue.  There has to be a single document element (e.g. some element wrapping the Test, Element, and Element2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use `@myattribute`, it will look for that attribute attached to the context node (in this case, the document element).

- If you are trying to evaluate whether the attribute is *anywhere* within the document, then you have to change your axis in your XPATH.
- If you are trying to evaluate whether the attribute is attached to a *particular element*, then you need to change your context (i.e. not the document element, but the `Element2` element).

Here are two potential solutions:

1. If you use the XPATH expression `//@Myattribute` it would scan the entire document looking for that attribute.
2. If you change your context to the `Element2` element, rather than the document element, then `@Myattribute` would be found.

Comment: What value should I pass to XAp_get_attribute_in_set to get the attribute taking into account my previous comment?

Comment: It takes only an integer (array index into nodeset..) I don't know beforehand where in my nodeset my attribute might appear

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that part carefully. You don't want to provide that XPATH there(that is what you specify further up). I'm not familiar with the TinyXPATH or TinyXML libraries.  If they are 0 based, then 0 is probably what you should pass in.  Your issue may not be that line, but that you haven't selected anything, so the set is empty.  Verify that `ns` is not null or empty first. If you haven't selected anything, then it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your node is of "String" type you can use directly the S_compute_xpath() function. 
Example:

```
TiXmlString ts = proc.S_compute_xpath();
```

Then you can convert `ts` in a "canonical" string by using  `ts.c_str()`.
It works either with attributes as with elements, but if you catch elements you get to add the function text() at the bottom of XPATH expression, like

```
xpath_processor xproc(doc.RootElement(),"/Documento/Element2/text()");
```

In addition, i think you have to include only one node of type "root".
Your XML will have to look like

```
<Documento>
        <Test></Test>
        <Element>Tony</Element>
        <Element2 Myattribute="12">Tb</Element2>
</Documento>
```

Paride.