# selecting xml elements

Tags: c++, attributes, element, nodes, tinyxml

i have an xml file that looks something like this

```
<library>
    <book name="ABC">
        <chapter val="1"/>
            ...
    </book>
            ...
    <book id="123">
        <page val="567"/>
            ...
    </book>
</library>
```

I am using tinyxml to parse this xml file. and I am doing this in C++. I want to select the 'chapter' element and here's my code...

```
TiXmlDocument doc;
TiXmlHandle XMLFileHandle( &doc);

TiXmlElement* Book1Element = XMLFileHandle.FirstChild("library").FirstChild("book").FirstChild("chapter").FirstChild.ToElement();
```

it works. but when i try to select the 'page' element the same way it didn't work.

```
TiXmlElement* Book2Element = XMLFileHandle.FirstChild("library").FirstChild("book").FirstChild("page").FirstChild.ToElement();
```

why is that? i have a feeling it might be because one book element has an attribute by name, and the other book element has an attribute by id.

this is my first time dealing with xml and tinyxml, i apologize if i used the wrong terminology, and if i need to further explain myself, just let me know.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the XML tree is exactly as you show it, this is not going to work, because you are still selecting the first `book` element, which has no `page` child.

Comment: so basically changing FirstChild("chapter") to FirstChild("page") does not do anything to change the selection of the book element? How should I do it then

Comment: @livelaughlove When you select the `book`, you need to find the right `book` element by its attribute. Have a look at the API documentation, you should find some help there.

Comment: Try 
TiXmlElement* Book2Element = XMLFileHandle.FirstChild("library").Child(2).FirstChild("page").FirstChild.ToElement()

Comment: I've never used this library btw just looked at the documentation http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlHandle.html

Comment: @reevesy i tried it and it didn't work and i think it's cause i left out some silbing nodes for books which messes up the index. that's my fault but i understand your approach, thanks

Comment: @livelaughlove, no probs mate, you'd probably be better of using xpath for this if possible....

Comment: @reevesy i've been looking that up, i understand the syntax of xpath and that it's an expression for selecting nodes. i just don't really understand how to implement it into my program, would xpath work with tinyxml? or is xpath like a parser on it's own

Comment: @livelaughlove not sure, im mainly use Java, JDOM/Jaxen however looks like you can use tinyxml and tinyxpath http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994747/get-attribute-using-xpath-with-tinyxpath-tinyxml - good luck.........

Answer (score 2):

Because the first Child of book does not have a page element. The Second child does